# pass ID variable to be used in a pop up window in HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

Heys guys

I am having trouble passing an ID variable to be used in a pop-up window in HTML

this is what I am trying to do

```
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from locations";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $locationID = $row['id'];
    
    <button class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\"> Show Listed Properties </button> 
// here i want to pass the locationID variable so that when the user clicks on the 
// button a pop up window appears displaying information based on the location id.
    
    }
    ?>
```

my pop up window looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                     
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      Hi there, I am a Modal Example for Dashio Admin Panel.
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

inside the popup code, I will be performing an SQL query based on the locationID variable and then populate the popup window with the query results.

alternatively, I could just create a new page and pass the id as a get request but I feel like that does not look as professional and is more time-consuming.

could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

add new class in the button and call it open-modal, and use data-id like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?= $id; ?>" data-target="#myModal">Show Listed Properties</button>
```

in the end of the file you can call it like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function () {
         var id = $(this).data('id');
         alert(id) 

        /*
        proceed with rest of modal using the id variable as necessary 
        */
    });
    </script>
```

hope I understand your issue well.

Comment: this gives the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: try to Reference jQuery first

Comment: could you explain a little?

Comment: that works thankyou, still a bit confused about the solution, would I be copying the modal code inside the script and performing sql queries inside of there? which doesnt make sense to me